# H2 database HTTPS connection

Tags: database, https, connection, h2

I'm using the H2 Database embedded mode to connect to local databases, but, is it possible to open a database file located on a remote server, using HTTPS?

The goal is to use a dropbox file: https://dl.dropbox.com/.../database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a HTTP(S) file system, using the [file system abstraction layer of H2](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#file_system).

Quite a few implementations are [included in H2](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/#) (reading from Jar, Zip, in-memory, NIO,...)

Comment: Thomas, can you point an example of a similar implementation? It would help a lot. Thanks.