# Cloud solution for H2 database

Tags: cloud, storage, h2

I need some informations about cloud computing.

What I need is a storage where the customer will have there h2 database synchronized. Each time there database change and a connection is available, db is synchronized. But it's a database of many GO. that can be 5go or more for the bigger. And it's just one big file.
So I want to know which solution exist to do this kind of things without need to reupload the entire database on changed ,cause it will probably take really much time.

Thank's

Comment: The solution could be to implement access through HTTP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240913/h2-database-https-connection

Comment: But it can't work if you don't have an internet access no ?

Comment: "Each time there database change and a connection is available"--- so, you want to work OFFLINE and synchronize (MERGE!!) the changes between "local" databases... that would be (almost) magic! The big issue here is not really the database upload, but the changes made on the local database files...